# Python: Unable to convert JSON file to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I have the code below which should convert a JSON file to a CSV file

```
import json
import csv

infractions = open("C:\\Users\\Alan\\Downloads\\open.json","r")
infractions_parsed = json.loads(infractions)
infractions_data = infractions_parsed['infractions']

# open a file for writing
csv_data = open('Data.csv', 'w')
# create the csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_data)
count = 0
for inf in infractions_data:
      if count == 0:
             header = inf.keys()
             csvwriter.writerow(header)
             count += 1
      csvwriter.writerow(inf.values())
employ_data.close()
```

However, I get this error. Any reason why this should be?

```
C:\Users\Alan\Desktop>python monkeytennis.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monkeytennis.py", line 5, in <module>
    infractions_parsed = json.loads(infractions)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

JSON is in format:

```
  {
      "count": 666,
      "query": "righthere",
      "infractions": [{
          "status": "open",
          "severity": 2.0,
          "title": "Blah blah blah",
          "coals": [1, 1],
          "date": "2017-04-22T23:10:07",
          "name": "Joe Bloggs"
      },...
```

Comment: Use `csv.DictWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

`infractions` is a file object, which can't be passed directly to `json.loads()`. Either read it first:

```
infractions_parsed = json.loads(infractions.read())
```

or use `json.load` (without the 's') which does expect a buffer.

```
infractions_parsed = json.load(infractions)
```